# Memory leak with AngularJS in IE8

Tags: jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

We are facing memory leak in our application when using it on IE8 however in other browsers memory build up is slow and memory is also getting released after some time. we have used AngularJS and created several directives to use JQuery plugins like datatable and JQuery dialog. we have tried Chrome profiler to debug the issue, memory build up is happening on change of route and we are able to see all the elements from previous screen as detached elements in the heap snapshot.

we have tried to delete detached element on $destroy event of $scope but it didn't help.
In heap snapshot we are also seeing other objects like array (consuming around 65% of the memory).

We are using angular.js 1.2.2 and JQuery 1.9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

You can use simply the ui-jq, ui-options to use any preexisting jquery plugins without having to create a directive for every plugin you want to use.

This saves you from introducing any new issues in this case perhaps memory leak.